# What free softtware (Windows 7) to use with a webcam

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I got a web-cam and I feels it's a bit underused.

So I'm wondering what free software I could use with it beside of the obvious Widows Messenger (or MSN or whatever it's name now) / Skype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

- [CamFrog](http://www.camfrog.com/) - live webcam video chat room software for Windows
- Make some fun with webcam using [ManyCam](http://download.cnet.com/ManyCam-Virtual-Webcam/3000-2348_4-10593500.html)
- Replace login window with face Recognition Software [Blink](http://www.luxand.com/)!
- As a security camera with [Dorgem](http://dorgem.sourceforge.net/) and [Tutorial](http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/09/27/how-to-use-your-pc-and-webcam-as-a-motion-detecting-and-recording-security-camera/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use WebCamXP5 (yeah, I know) to set up a streaming media server so you could watch your home/office while you are away or use ManyCam for effects.

Also, ChatRoulette...but use at your peril.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Talk](http://www.google.com/talk/) and [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) both support webcams

Comment: Only GTalk in pidgin supports webcam, no other protocols do. And only in linux i think.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW , Google Talk supports webcam , but you need install a plugin by Google.